# Different chess board using skak package

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak, skak

Is it possible to set up a different chess board size, say 4x16, using skak package?

Answer (score 2):

No. At least, the `chessboard` manual notes this limitation specifically (p. 71):

> As arguments in the commands of the package skak you can only use the
>   fields of a 8×8-board.

Presumably, this is not really very surprising given its purpose and basic assumptions.

There is no problem creating a chessboard with different dimensions, of course, but `skak` is concerned with typesetting games, which involve much more than merely drawing boards.

[image: 4x16 board]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[LSB,LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x16}{%
  maxfield=d16,
  borderwidth=10mm,
  boardfontencoding=LSBC3,
  color=white,
  colorwhitebackfields,
  color=black,
  colorblackbackfields,
  blackfieldmaskcolor=black,
  whitepiececolor=yellow,
  whitepiecemaskcolor=red,
  blackpiececolor=cyan,
  blackpiecemaskcolor=blue,
  addfontcolors,
  pgfstyle=border,
  color=white,
  markregion=a1-d16,
  }
\begin{document}
  \chessboard[
    style=4x16,
    setpieces={Qa8,Qb4,Qc1,Qd3,Qb16,Qc12,Qa7,Qc15,qa1,qb14,qc11,qd13,qb6,qc2,qa4,qc5},
    padding=1ex,
  ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am surprised with 'LSB' and 'LSBC3'; they aren't mentioned in 'encguide.pdf', a document that I found in CTAN but isn't part of my MiKTeX installation. Can you gives us an idea of what are those encodings?

Comment: @djnavas Isn't `L` reserved for `local` encodings? I assume the idea was local to installation, but I guess this is local in some extended sense. (`LY1` was a mistake, I think.) I'm sure `encguide.pdf` covers this, though.

Comment: @djnavas: The LSB & friends encodings are explained in the chessfss documentation. The "L" means local in the sense "local to a package" - I discussed the naming when I choosed it and it was agreed that it is ok.

Comment: @cfr I never make mistakes:-) LY1 meant local to Y&Y tex installations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then most of the uses of LY1 were mistakes.