# Typesetting irregular games of chess

Tags: chess, skak

I'm writing a Latex document describing games of chess with irregularly sized and shaped boards.  I have read both the [`skak`](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/texmate/texmate2manual.pdf) and [`xskak`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xskak/xskak.pdf) and as far as I can tell they only support standard 8x8 boards.  Does a more general chess typesetting package exist?  If not how might I emulate such boards in the existing packages?

Here is a very small board I managed to mark up in tikz:

[image: ChessBoard]

Comment: [Related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358040/different-chess-board-using-skak-package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could misuse the hidefields-key. The main problem is the border: you will probably have to redraw it which could get a bit tiring if there are many turns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}

\setchessboard{boardfontencoding=LSBC3}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\board@do@printfieldempty[2]{%fileNr, rankNr
  \ifthenelse%
     {\board@test@iswhitefield{#1}{#2}}%white field
    {}% {\@nameuse{board@\board@val@game @piece@empty@white}}%
    {}% {\@nameuse{board@\board@val@game @piece@empty@black}}%
     }
\makeatother     

\begin{document}

\newchessgame
\chessboard[whitefieldmaskcolor=gray!50!white,addfontcolors,
            border=false,
            printarea=a1-c3,
            hidefields={b3,c1,c3},
            showmover=false]

\end{document}
```

[image]