# Special chessboard

Tags: chess, chessboard

How can I create the following chessboard with LaTex ?

[image]

Thank you in advance

**Update**

[image]

```
\usepackage{xskak,xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\setchessboard{boardfontencoding=LSBC3}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\board@do@printfieldempty[2]{%fileNr, rankNr
    \ifthenelse%
    {\board@test@iswhitefield{#1}{#2}}%white field
    {}% {\@nameuse{board@\board@val@game @piece@empty@white}}%
    {}% {\@nameuse{board@\board@val@game @piece@empty@black}}%
}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \newchessgame
        \chessboard[whitefieldmaskcolor=gray!50!white,addfontcolors,
        border=false,
        printarea=a1-h8,
        hidefields={a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8,
                    b1, b2, b3, b6, b7, b8,
                    c1, c2, c7, c8,
                    d1, d8,                      
                    f8, f1,
                    g1, g2, g7, g8,
                    h1, h2, h3, h6, h7, h8},
        setwhite={rc6, rd5, re4, rf3},
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        markboard,
        pgfstyle=border,
        boardfontsize=30pt,
        showmover=false]
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post what you've got so far as MWE.

Comment: See the answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133338/117534 and friends. Might be of some help. If you're stuck, post what you have and then ask a specific question relating to the problem you are facing. Currently the question is a do-it-for-me, which is not attractive to most people here.

Comment: Check also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358694/2388

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include answers. If you have an answer of your own, post it as an answer. It is very confusing when questions contain answers to them!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realized this with the `chessboard` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{%
  showmover=false,
  boardfontencoding=LSBC3,
  blackfieldmaskcolor=BlanchedAlmond,
  whitefieldmaskcolor=BurlyWood!30!brown,
  blackfieldcolor=BlanchedAlmond,
  setfontcolors,
  label=false,
  border=false,
  maxfield=g8,
  hidefields={a1,a2,a3,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b7,b8,c1,c8,e1,e8,f1,f2,f7,f8,g1,g2,g3,g6,g7,g8}
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\board@do@printfieldempty[2]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chessboard[setpieces={Rb6,Rc5,Rd4,Re3}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

- For the diamond shape of the chess board, I followed [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358694/2388): I specify with the `hidefields` key which fields are not needed, and redefine `\board@do@printfieldempty` to not print these fields. Additionally, you need to remove the outer border (`border=false`). Since the layout fits inside 7x8 cells, I set this size as `maxfield`.
- For the colors, I use `BlanchedAlmond` and `BurlyWood!30!brown` from the `xcolor` package with the `svgnames` option. These are specified in the three keys `blackfieldmaskcolor`, `whitefieldmaskcolor` and `blackfieldcolor` (note: I swapped black and white to get exactly your example). `setfontcolors` then guarantees that these colors are actually used.