# How to color white chess pieces black?

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I need a chessgame with just one piece color where I can make my moves and each additional board after `\mainline` stays in the color, black pieces stays black and the white pieces get black. The default board with white and gray fields shoudn't change (if it's possible, but the most important thing is that the figures have the same color)! I tried different packages (xskak, chessboard), different commands like `\setchessboard`, `\whitepiececolor`, I even ask chat GPT, but it doesn't work. Also I found this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358040/different-chess-board-using-skak-package/358041#358041), changing the piece colors didn't work.

This is my code yet:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage[LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Command whitepiececolor=black}

\setchessboard{smallboard, showmover=false, whitepiececolor=black,}
\newchessgame[setfen=8/8/8/3p4/4R2/8/B4n2/8 w -- 1 0]
\chessboard
\mainline{1.Bd5} 
\chessboard
\mainline{1... Ne4}
\chessboard
\mainline{2.Be4}
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: well it wouldn't be too difficult to exchange the pieces, but I don't see how it would help you. For skak the white pieces would still be the white pieces and that means they are the one who would move in the first half move and black would move in the second half move. That means you can't move with the same piece twice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's okay, but I need it for solo chess. I need a board with just one color. So how does it work?

Comment: `\cbReDefineNewPiece{white}{R}{\BlackRookOnWhite}{\BlackRookOnBlack}
\cbReDefineNewPiece{white}{B}{\BlackBishopOnWhite}{\BlackBishopOnBlack}` and so on. But as I wrote: I don't think that it will give what you need.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's exactly what I needed for my solo chess examples. Thank you!